# How to get plot graph in weka?

Tags: graph, machine-learning, weka

**Weka** allows to analyse scatter plots of points vs classes. Is it possible to analyse these points in graph(continuous line) plot?

Comment: To better understand your question, can you please provide an example of what you are looking for?